# How to center align tables in the Ag-Grid in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am new to Ag-Grid React, I have created the table but by default, they are aligned on the left side. Can anyone tell me how to center align tables in `AgGridReact`?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply certain style on the column by declaring a [`CellStyle`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/cell-styles/#cell-style) object in the column definition. If you want all columns to be centered:

```js
<AgGridReact
  {...props}
  defaultColDef={{
    cellStyle: () => ({
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center"
    })
  }}
/>
```

However if you only want to center align a specific column, put the `cellStyle` object in that column definition instead:

```js
{
  headerName: "Country",
  field: "country",
  width: 120,
  cellStyle: () => ({
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  })
},
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66820891/how-to-aligncenter-for-tables-in-the-ag-grid-in-react-js]